# How to fix radio button default with two radio button different field

Tags: javascript, python, web

I have two radio button different field name in website. first radiobutton delivery_option (I made by self) , second radio button (carrier_id) . I want to relation between two radio button. If I check on delivery_option automatic check radio button carrier_id. How to fix it?

```
    <template id="delivery_opt" inherit_id="website_sale.payment" customize_show="True" name="Delivery Option">

        <xpath expr="//div[@id='payment_method']" position="before">

            <div class="row" id="delivery_option">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
              <h4>Choose your Delivery</h4>
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                      <li>
                          <label>
                              <input value="once" type="radio" name="delivery_options"
                                t-att-checked="order.delivery_options == 'once' and 'checked' or False"
                                />
                              <span>Every day</span>
                          </label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <label>
                              <input value="twice"  type="radio" name="delivery_options"
                                t-att-checked="order.delivery_options == 'twice' and 'checked' or False"
                                  />
                              <span>Every two day</span>
                          </label>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>

  </xpath>

</template>

<template id="delivery_method_def" name="Delivery Method Default" inherit_id="website_sale.payment">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='payment_method']" position="before">
        <div t-if="deliveries" class="row" id="delivery_carrier">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
            <h4>Choose your Delivery Method</h4>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li t-foreach="deliveries" t-as="delivery">
                        <t t-if="delivery.available">
                            <label>
                                <input t-att-value="delivery.id" type="radio" name="delivery_type"
                                    t-att-checked="order.carrier_id and order.carrier_id.id == delivery.id and 'checked' or False"/>
                                <abbr t-att-title="delivery.website_description"><span t-field="delivery.name"/></abbr>
                                <span class="badge" t-field="delivery.price"
                                    t-options='{
                                        "widget": "monetary",
                                        "from_currency": delivery.product_id.company_id.currency_id,
                                        "display_currency": website_sale_order.currency_id
                                    }'/>
                                <div t-field="delivery.website_description" class="text-muted"/>
                            </label>
                        </t>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Use javaScript event function when you change your delivery_options field the other field will also change if delivery_options value is true.And also give id to carrier_id.

```
  <input value="once" type="radio" name="delivery_options"  id="delivery" onchange="myFunction()"                            t-att-checked="order.delivery_options == 'once' and 'checked' or False"/>
       <script>
        function myFunction() {
                  if($("#delivery_option").checked === true){
                 $("#carrier_id").val() = "true"
           }
              }
        </script>
```

Comment: Dear Salman thanks for your reply, I use .py and .xml .    I try with this                             order.write({'carrier_id': 1})
print 'order.carrier_id', order.carrier_id.id  but I only get one value with Id. I want to change with many value. carrier_id field type many2one

Comment: can you please share with me your code. or kindly elaborate it.

Comment: my code .xml same as above and my code in .py      _inherit = 'sale.order'

    delivery_options = fields.Selection([
        ('once', 'Every day'),
        ('twice', 'Every two days')],
        string='Delivery Options'
    )